# Build failed mainline

Tags: kernel, compiling

Was waiting eagerly for Linux 4.17-rc2. It was late. Turns out build failed for some archs.

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.17-rc2/

But also, the ones that succeeded (such as amd64) are unsigned. They are also anaemic at about 7MB compared to over 50MB for normal generic images from the mainline.

Why are they unsigned, and why are they so small, just because builds for other architectures failed?

Thank you for any information!

Comment: Turns out since then, some deb files appeared with modules - they must be separating them from the image file.

Comment: Still does not explain why they are unsigned. I cannot be bothered disabling Secure Boot and then have Windows have a hissy fit and dump the TPM, demanding the recovery key. Hence, I hope they sign it soon. I am hoping it will fix some of the nasty regressions in 4.17-rc1 compared to 4.16.2.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as you could not get it to build i got it working in the end by downloading each part from the mainline directory http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.17-rc2/ but it then shows as not installed so leaving the 3 parts still installed i then used this tool http://www.teejeetech.in/p/ukuu-kernel-upgrade-utility.html and clicked on 4.17-rc2 on the list and hit install it then installed fine
hope this helps.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question(s), why the kernels are unsigned and small.

Comment: true i miss read sorry but it dose provide a way to install it and i have no issues with windows 10 using it either :)

Comment: I know how to install it from source without a utility. You basically dump them in /boot dir and sudo update-grub. But the secure boot will need to be disabled, and that is what bothers me. But thanks for replying. :)

Comment: Okay, does anybody know who to complain to? It's still unfixed and clearly nobody is doing anything about it.

Comment: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.17-rc3/
These people are just useless. Not only have they not fixed the rc2 from last week, their rc3 is completely botched, with no actual build information whatsoever.